# Directory for importing minted snippets

Tags: minted, import

Is there a way to tell `minted` to import the snippets from a certain directory? I'm looking for something similar to the way `\graphicspath{{img/}}` works for images.

Right now, all the files I need to import get mixed with my other `.tex` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is not available in the current `minted`. Redefining `\inputminted` is out of the question, I'm afraid, because it has different definitions according to whether `draft` is on or off.

Anyhow, you can quite easily define a wrapper around `\inputminted`. The syntax of `\pathinputminted` is the same as `\inputminted`:

> `\pathinputminted[<options>]{<language>}{<filename>}`

Full code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mintedpath}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_paulie_mintedpath_seq { } { #1 }
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g_paulie_mintedpath_seq { }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_paulie_mintedpath_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\pathinputminted}{O{}mm}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_paulie_mintedpath_seq
   {
    \file_if_exist:nT { ##1 #3 }
     {
      \inputminted[#1]{#2}{##1 #3}
      \seq_map_break:
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\mintedpath{ {sub1/} {sub2/} }

\begin{document}

\pathinputminted{latex}{test1.tex} % this is only in sub1

\pathinputminted{latex}{test2.tex} % this is both in sub1 and sub2

\pathinputminted{latex}{test3.tex} % this is only in sub2

\pathinputminted{latex}{test4.tex} % this is both in current directory and sub1

\end{document}
```

This is the directory structure I set up for the purpose of the example, after the document has been typeset once, so the Pygments files are already shown.

```
paulie > ls -R
_minted-paulie/ paulie.log  paulie.tex  sub2/
paulie.aux  paulie.pdf  sub1/       test4.tex

./_minted-paulie:
24A365234AE4FDB0DF45E303775CC522F86A94839C3F0079C692F025CF998383.pygtex
4CF555EB3B29AA33E0D843E51AE34A9128809557B179BB64CA75D7BABAABEFE2.pygtex
D3967FFDA37461EF76D39CC2F8B40FCC93A75DBBC5197FD7555A181B29CF5ABC.pygtex
FD1CB1B77BD8698379A00F3A3BED29F678CA5D356D6BB9C6FD6DCBC2BA6DFEA3.pygtex
default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle
default.pygstyle

./sub1:
test1.tex   test2.tex

./sub2:
test2.tex   test3.tex   test4.tex
```

As you see from the output

[image]

only the first hit is input. I added an implicit `./` at the beginning of the search paths, so a file in the working directory is found first and, like in the other cases, further searching is not performed.

Comment: Is there a way to use your solution with the `\newmintedfile` command?

Comment: @Paulie I'd say no.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `\inputminted[<options>]{<language>}{<filename>}`.

In `<filename>` you can indicate the complete path (remember to use `\` (not `/`) also for Windows paths.

If you want to set a fixed path, you can simple create a new command, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\myminted}[1]{\inputminted{latex}{/my/dir/#1}}

\begin{document}

\myminted{main.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already know how to do that. I'm asking if there is a way to declare the folder (`\mintedpath{my/dir/}`, for example), so that I can just write `\inputminted{<language>}{snippet.snip}` to import the snippet.

Comment: @Paulie Just create a new command, see my renewed answer.

Comment: I like your approach, but a new command would have to be defined for every `minted` language and set of options, right?

Comment: @Paulie Alternatively, you can define a new command with more than one parameter: one for the file name, the others for the other opinions.